# What is the integer "1" in 'cursor.getString(1)' means?

Tags: android

May I know what does integer "1" or other integer filled in this bracket in cursor.getString(1) means?

Thanks

Comment: Oh for goodness sake, please [witness the magic of reading the Android Developer's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the column *index.*

For example, if the query was `select a, b, c from ...`, column index 1 would be `b` (being zero-based, the column indexes for that query are `0 = a`, `1 = b` and `2 = c`).

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) for more detail.

An alternative would be to use `cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("b"))` assuming you're certain that column exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is Column Index in Cursor, returned from query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the integer is the zero-based index of the column you want to retrieve:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)